# How to run mocha 6 w/ babel 7 and TypeScript 3.7?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, babeljs

How can I run my mocha tests with Babel and TypeScript?

The command I'm trying is:

```
node_modules/.bin/mocha --require @babel/register "src/**/*.spec.ts"
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
.../src/Sql.spec.ts:1
import 'mocha';
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

My `.babelrc` looks like:

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env",{"targets": {"node": "10.7"}}],
        ["@babel/preset-typescript",{"allowNamespaces": true}]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-bigint",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",{"loose": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",{"loose": true}]
    ],
    "comments": false
}
```

And when I build my code for prod via

```
node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir dist --extensions ".ts" --source-maps inline
```

That very same `Sql.spec.js` file compiles away the `import` as expected:

```
"use strict";

require("mocha");

var _chai = require("chai");
```

So what's going on? Is mocha not including `@babel/register`? Is `@babel/register` not doing its job? Are they ignoring the `.babelrc` file?

Comment: have you checked this https://github.com/mochajs/mocha-examples/tree/master/packages/typescript-babel

Comment: @anoop No, hadn't seen that. That works!! Thank you.